# SVN-related tools

Tags: svn, process, release-management

I'm getting more and more annoyed about some processes that could probably be automatically improved.

Indeed, I would like to know if there are some tools that manage to:

- "force" commit message structure
- generate automatic changelog between two specific tags
- notify users by email when a maintenance branch (actually, any branch we want) is created

Of course, I could do these by myself (not necessarily easy but doable), I just don't want to waste my time reinventing the wheel.

We're using Subversion, Hudson and Trac at work, just in case some of their plugins could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "force" by using a pre-commit hook script which checks the format ...
2. get the revisions of the tags an use svn2cl
3. any kind of mailing tool in post-commit hook script...URL for references is given in other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to add post-commit hook scripts in subversion.

Relevant page in the SVN book is here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks